# Top bar new rep notification icon's title doesn't auto change

Tags: bug, top-bar

When you get new rep changes, on the "new rep change notification box" (ie green box with rep change number in it, such as +5) the popup title when hovering doesn't change state to match with the new rep box itself.

The new green box appears automatically where as the popup title on hover doesn't - it needs a page refresh.

**TEST 1**

1. New rep change comes in, green box with +5 in it appears automatically, hovering the new box shows the default popup title:

   > Recent achievements: reputation, badges, and privileges earned
2. Clicking the green rep box brings up the drop down list of what changed (rep, badges, etc). Moved the mouse away from drop down and it and the new green box went away.
3. Hovering what is now the default grey image (a graphic equaliser?) I still get:

   > Recent achievements: reputation, badges, and privileges earned

**TEST 2**

1. New rep change comes in, green box with +5 in it appears automatically, hovering the new box shows the default popup title:

   > Recent achievements: reputation, badges, and privileges earned
2. Refreshed the page and hovering the new box shows the correct popup title:

   > You have new reputation changes
3. Clicked the green rep box brought up the drop down list of what changed (rep, badges, etc).
   moved the mouse away from drop down and it and the new green box went away.
   Hovering what is now the default grey image (a graphic equaliser?) I still get:

   > You have new reputation changes

I guess one is ajax and the other isn't?  Really not *bothered*, just reporting.